# Mongoose find query vs $match

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a following document inside mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a25f1b19c72e07ffc50a37d"),
    "name" : "test",
    "category" : ObjectId("5a1e6622a7739fb64c8c530b"),
    "recentDeveloperComment" : ObjectId("5a25f1b19c72e07ffc50a37c"),
    "fileName" : "test2.xlsx",
    "rawData" : ObjectId("5a21079ef99e75b2140fb77a"),
    "group" : {
        "year" : 2017,
        "month" : 1,
        "category" : "test1"
    },
    "unlocked" : false,
    "status" : "Pending",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-12-05T01:08:40.465Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-05T01:08:40.465Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I can match this by using following find query with mongoose

```
Repo.find({'group.year' : year, 'group.month' : month, 'group.category' : category, name:repo})
    .exec((err, repoResult) => {
        //matches one document
    })
```

However with the below aggregate $match I cannot get the same result

```
Repo.aggregate([
    {
        $match:
            {
                $and:[
                    {'group.year' : year},
                    {'group.month' : month},
                    {'group.category' : category},
                    {name : repo}
                ]
            }
    },
]).exec((err, commitsResult) => {
    //matches zero document
});
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

It was because `find` parses all the query strings into the variable type that is defined in the database. For example `year` was a parameter parsed from url so it was a string form but in Mongodb the field is defined as an int. `Find` automatically parses this to the correct type but `$match` does not parse it so it has to be done manually.