# Querying with mongoose: how to parce a Mongo _id?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, match, aggregate

I found this similar question to mine, but without explanation [Mongoose find query vs $match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645000/mongoose-find-query-vs-match), I'm trying to do something similar.

I manage to filter by today's date correctly, but I can not yet filter by client's ID.

this works:

```
 var today = new Date(dateTime);    
    
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
                var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 1!
                var mmd = String(today.getMonth()).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    
        const filter = {
                    $match: {
                        $and: [
                            { date: { $gt: new Date(Date.UTC(yyyy, mmd, dd)) } },
                            // { client: '5f78a00e97f9aa002aa7ec1c' },
                            { status: 1 }
                        ]
                    }
                };
        
// the correct date is whit mmd not mm
                const dateSent = new Date(Date.UTC(yyyy, mmd, dd));
                console.log(dateSent);
        
                const wpreservationDbagregate = await WorkplaceReservation.aggregate([filter]);
       
                
                res.json(wpreservationDbagregate);
```

I got this response, older documents are being correctly filtered:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f7b93e89d1cb4600e8ce740",
        "status": 1,
        "workplace": 5,
        "date": "2020-10-09T00:00:00.000Z",
        "creator": "5f7b36b090b6e518210c6070",
        "client": "5f78a00e97f9aa002aa7ec1c",
        "userId": "5f7b36b090b6e518210c6070",
        "dateCreated": "2020-10-05T21:45:12.229Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f7b95699d1cb4600e8ce742",
        "status": 1,
        "workplace": 2,
        "date": "2020-10-07T00:00:00.000Z",
        "creator": "5f7b36b090b6e518210c6070",
        "client": "5f78a00e97f9aa002aa7ec1c",
        "userId": "5f7b36b090b6e518210c6070",
        "dateCreated": "2020-10-05T21:51:37.219Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

but when tying to filter by client Id it doesnt work, even with the string (it is commented out in the filter constant)

I suppose i have to parse it somehow, but I can find the way...

this is the schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const workplaceReservationSchema = new Schema({
    client: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user', required: [true, 'El espacio de trabajo debe ser reservado para algun Cliente'] },
    workplace: { type: Number, required: [true, 'El espacio de trabajo es un campo obligatorio'] },
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user', required: [true, 'El espacio de trabajo debe ser reservado para algun usuario'] },
    creator: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user', required: [true, 'Loging incorrecto'] },
    date: { type: Date, required: [true, 'La reserva debe tener una fecha'] },
    dateModified: { type: Date },
    dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    status: { type: Number, default: 1 }
});

//Set unique compound indexes
workplaceReservationSchema.index({ workplace: 1, client: 1, date: 1, status: 1 }, { unique: true });
workplaceReservationSchema.index({ userId: 1, client: 1, date: 1, status: 1 }, { unique: true });


const WorkplaceReservation = mongoose.model('workplaceReservation', workplaceReservationSchema);

export default WorkplaceReservation;
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/node": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
        "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
        "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.6.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.10.7",
        "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.3",
        "morgan": "^1.10.0",
        "underscore": "^1.10.2"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried converting the _id from string to ObjectId ?
Something like `{ client: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5f78a00e97f9aa002aa7ec1c') }`

Answer (score 0):

You usually want to keep the variable in the schema for the Object ID implicit (undeclared, let Mongo handle it)

And for your userID and creator variables, use `type: String`

```
// Schema
const workplaceReservationSchema = new Schema({
    workplace: { type: Number, required: [true, 'El espacio de trabajo es un campo obligatorio'] },
    userId: { type: String, ref: 'user', required: [true, 'El espacio de trabajo debe ser reservado para algun usuario'] },
    creator: { type: String, ref: 'user', required: [true, 'Loging incorrecto'] },
    date: { type: Date, required: [true, 'La reserva debe tener una fecha'] },
    dateModified: { type: Date },
    dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    status: { type: Number, default: 1 }
});
```

then your query can be structured like this:

```
const filter = {
    $match: {
        $and: [
            { date: { $gt: new Date(Date.UTC(yyyy, mmd, dd)) } },
            { _id: '5f78a00e97f9aa002aa7ec1c' },
            { status: 1 }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, I will try use type string and check this solution!

Comment: Stephen, for some reason (I am new using mongoose), when I change the userID and creator variables from Schema.Types.ObjectId to use type: String, the unique compound indexes they are part of, doesn't create. I went with Georgios Solution  with mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5f78a00e97f9aa002aa7ec1c') in the filter and it worked, but I really wanted to simplify the query like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I finally finished this query. the main idea was to group by date (that is why i did not use find)

here is the final code:

```
 // Actual GTM -3 DATETIME (Argentina)
        const dateTime = new Date(new Date() - 3600 * 1000 * 3).toISOString();
        var today = new Date(dateTime);
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 1!
        var mmd = String(today.getMonth()).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        // Actual GTM -3 Date
        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

        const filter = {
            $match: {
                $and: [
                    { date: { $gt: new Date(Date.UTC(yyyy, mmd, dd)) } },
                    { client: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(client) },
                    { status: 1 }
                ]
            }
        };

        const group = {
            $group: {
                _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        };
        const wpreservationDbfiltered = await WorkplaceReservation.aggregate([filter]);
        const wpreservationDbgrouped = await WorkplaceReservation.aggregate([filter, group]);

        res.status(200).json({ wpreservationDbgrouped, wpreservationDbfiltered });
```

I got the data grouped by date and also all the documents like this:

```
{
    "wpreservationDbgrouped": [
        {
            "_id": "2020-10-09",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "2020-10-07",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "_id": "2020-10-08",
            "count": 1
        }
    ],
    "wpreservationDbfiltered": [
        {
            "_id": "5f7c87d4670b421d387d2614",
            "status": 1,
            "workplace": 2,
            "date": "2020-10-07T00:00:00.000Z",
            "creator": "5f790ad4cb0b41834f94e91b",
            "client": "5f78dac286bfd05f21527e49",
            "userId": "5f790ad4cb0b41834f94e91b",
            "dateCreated": "2020-10-06T15:05:56.258Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f7c929ed1901826d50af73d",
            "status": 1,
            "workplace": 3,
            "date": "2020-10-08T00:00:00.000Z",
            "creator": "5f790ad4cb0b41834f94e91b",
            "client": "5f78dac286bfd05f21527e49",
            "userId": "5f790ad4cb0b41834f94e91b",
            "dateCreated": "2020-10-06T15:51:58.621Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f7c92a5d1901826d50af73e",
            "status": 1,
            "workplace": 6,
            "date": "2020-10-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "creator": "5f790ad4cb0b41834f94e91b",
            "client": "5f78dac286bfd05f21527e49",
            "userId": "5f790ad4cb0b41834f94e91b",
            "dateCreated": "2020-10-06T15:52:05.373Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

thanks a lot for your help!!